# Display all values of list in JList using Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jlist, defaultlistmodel

This is my code:

```
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  /* The data as a list of Persons.
  */
  private static List<PersonModel> personData = new ArrayList<PersonModel>();

  public static JList<PersonModel> jlist;


  public void init() {

      // Add some sample data
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Hans", "Muster"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Ruth", "Mueller"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Heinz", "Kurz"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Cornelia", "Meier"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Werner", "Meyer"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Lydia", "Kunz"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Anna", "Best"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Stefan", "Meier"));
      personData.add(new PersonModel("Martin", "Mueller"));

      String dataQ = " ";


      for(int i = 0; i < personData.size(); i++){
            dataQ = personData.get(i).getLastName() + " " + personData.get(i).getFirstName();
      }
      String[] arr = new String[] { dataQ };
      jlist = new JList(arr);
```

But it only displays the last record. How can I display all of the records/values? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `String variable` and not `array of String`,So while iterating in loop it is storing last value of `Arraylist personData` in `dataQ variable`.Try this,

```
int size=personData.size();//get size of personData
String dataQ[]=new String[size];//change String dataQ to dataQ[]; 

 for(int i = 0; i < personData.size(); i++)
      {
            dataQ[i] = personData.get(i).getLastName() + " " + personData.get(i).getFirstName();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `Jlist#toArray` method to get an array representation of your list.

```
jList = new JList(personData.toArray(new PersonModel[personData.size()]);
```

At this point, of course, you would need to supply a `ListCelLRenderer` to render the values.

A better approach would be to use a ListModel directly.  Something like...

```
public class PersonListModel extends AbstractListModel<PersonModel>{

    private List<PersonModel> people;

    public PersonListModel(List<PersonModel> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonModel getElementAt(int index) {
        return people.get(index);
    }

}
```

Then you could just do...

```
JList jList = new JList(new PersonListModel(personData));
```

Check out [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] arr = new String[]; 

for(int i = 0; i < personData.size(); i++){
            dataQ = personData.get(i).getLastName() + " " + personData.get(i).getFirstName();
arr [i] = dataQ;
      }

      jlist = new JList(arr);
```

try this